# golang: client declared and not used

Tags: go, elasticsearch

Estoy haciendo pruebas con la libreria de go para elasticsearch:
https://github.com/olivere/elastic

Tengo el siguiente código que es mi libreria para conectarme al servidor de Elasticsearch:

```
package elasticsearch

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5"
    "context"
)

var client *elastic.Client

func init() {

    var err error

    client, err := elastic.NewClient(
        elastic.SetURL(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_ENTRYPOINT")),
        elastic.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"), os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD")),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func Ping() (string, error) {

    ctx := context.Background()
    info, code, err := client.Ping(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_ENTRYPOINT")).Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("Elasticsearch returned with code %d and version %s", code, info.Version.Number)
    return msg, nil

}
```

Y mi programa principal es el siguiente:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/hectorgool/gomicrosearch3/elasticsearch"
)

func main() {

    if result, err := elasticsearch.Ping(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("ElasticSearch result: '%s'\n", result)
    }

}
```

Pero al hacer ejecutar el programa con:

```
go run main.go
```

Me muestra lo siguiente:

elasticsearch/elasticsearch.go:18: client declared and not used

La línea 18 corresponde al siguiente bloque de código:

```
client, err := elastic.NewClient(
    elastic.SetURL(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_ENTRYPOINT")),
    elastic.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"), os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD")),
)
```

Alguien puede decirme que es lo que le falta al programa o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

El error que te está notificando el compilador se debe a que estás declarando una variable que no estás utilizado, en este caso *client*. Recuerda que en Go no se pueden definir variables si luego estas no son utilizadas.

Si bien has definido *client* con alcance de paquete, en la función *init* has utilizado el operador := para definir una nueva variable *client*, en este caso con alcance local, y esta se ha sobrepuesto a la variable *client* global, por lo que al finalizar la ejecución de la función el compilador de Go detecta que no se ha utilizado la variable *client* local.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo vas a usar el valor de err y no el de client tenes que reemplazar client por "_" , es decir

```
_, err := elastic.NewClient(
    elastic.SetURL(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_ENTRYPOINT")),
    elastic.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"), 
os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD")),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**La variable Cliente que está declarando en el Init es una Nueva**
Tu función `elastic.NewClient` declara 2 nuevas variables cuando utilizas el `:=` para evitar esto antes del `elastic.NewClient` crea la variable `err` del tipo `error` y setea las 2 variables con los valores de `NewClient`.

```
func init() {

    var err error
    // Utilizar el = de esta manera no crea una nueva variable
    // si no que le das sus respectivos valores
    client, err = elastic.NewClient(
        elastic.SetURL(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_ENTRYPOINT")),
        elastic.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"), os.Getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD")),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

> De esta manera funciona correctamente sin errores de variables declaradas y no utilizadas